# Auto layout constraints.constant is not updating

Tags: ios, autolayout

In view will appear I am changing my constraints.constant value and logged the subview's frame 
It is as expected. But it is not updating in the view....

Comment: This is your answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26667006/uiview-addsubview-auto-layout-not-working/26668575#26668575

Answer (score 0):

Try doing:

```
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

After changing the constant value.

If that doesn't work try:

```
[self.view updateConstraintsIfNeeded];
```