# uitableview height does not change dynamically in swift ios?

Tags: ios, uitableview, swift

I'm in trouble.I have a city list, I want to display cities in `UITableView` and  I have disabled UITableView's scroll because i don't want to display scroll.

when I changed to UITableView's height dynamically, it doesn't changed and UITableView does not display all cities. Below the code. Please look it.

```
import UIKit

class FlightDetailsOneWayViewController: UIViewController {

var flightDetailArr:[FlightDetailsOneWay]  =  [FlightDetailsOneWay]()

@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!

@IBOutlet var scrollview: UIScrollView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    flightDetailArr.append(FlightDetailsOneWay(depCity: "London"))

    flightDetailArr.append(FlightDetailsOneWay(depCity: "China"))

    flightDetailArr.append(FlightDetailsOneWay(depCity: "Singapore"))

    flightDetailArr.append(FlightDetailsOneWay(depCity: "Dubai"))


    self.tableView.scrollEnabled = false

    var cellHeight  = CGFloat(self.tableView.rowHeight)

    var totalCity   = CGFloat(flightDetailArr.count)

    var totalHeight = cellHeight * totalCity

    self.tableView.frame.size.height = CGFloat(totalHeight)


}

  override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
       super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
      // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
   }


   func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int   {
       return flightDetailArr.count
   }


   func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) -> UITableViewCell!
     {
       let cell:FlightDetailsCell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("FlightDetail") as FlightDetailsCell
       let flight = flightDetailArr[indexPath.row]
       cell.setCell(flight.depCity)
       return cell
     }
}

class FlightDetailsOneWay
  {
      var depCity  =  ""
      init(depCity: String)
       {
         self.depCity =  depCity
        }
 }


class FlightDetailsCell: UITableViewCell {


  @IBOutlet var depCity: UILabel!


  override func awakeFromNib()
   {
      super.awakeFromNib()
      // Initialization code
   }

  override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool)
   {
       super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
       // Configure the view for the selected state
   }

  func setCell(depCity: String)
    {
        self.depCity.text  =  depCity
    }
}
```

below the preview of above code.

[image: preview]

Comment: You need to add constraint to change dynamic height for table view. See this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27414052/moving-views-with-constraints/27420696#27420696

Comment: @Kampai can you suggest how to connect a NSLayoutConstraint variable with height constraints.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As explanation required to this answer is very detailed.

Follow my other answer **["Moving views with constraints"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27414052/moving-views-with-constraints)** to get idea about how to update layout constraint.

And as per your comment about *how to connect NSLayoutConstraint variable with height constraints?* as below:

1. Go to Storyboard.
2. Select `UIView` in which you have added constraint. Click on **Constraints** icon to see all constraints. Right now in below image I have added only one constraint you may find more than that. Check for which constraint you have change it's properties.

[image]

3. Now click on **view controller** and Click on **Show the connection inspector**. here you can see all IBOutlets defined in your view controller. As in below image you can see I have created only one IBOutlet for sake of simplicity which is `heightConstraint`.

[image]

4. And this is how you can add connection to constraint variable.

[image]

Comment: when we apply height constraints on UITableView, it does not display simulator.

Comment: What is the constant value of height constraint initially? I mean in storyboard constraint property.

Answer (score 2):

You can use prototype cell if all your cell will have the same look:

[a complete tutorial  to make a project using prototype cell](http://www.raywenderlich.com/50308/storyboards-tutorial-in-ios-7-part-1)

or

[a second which it more quick to read](http://www.ioscreator.com/tutorials/prototype-cells-tableview-tutorial-ios8-swift)

You can can also use

```
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath 
{
  return 42.0
}
```

This function is perfect if you resize dynamically the height cell.

You just need to use: `beginUpdates()` and `endUpdates()` for make it works.

Comment: i want to increase a UITableView height, not a UITableView cell height.