# Width and Height NSLayoutConstraints on UIImageView not working

Tags: ios, swift, layout, interface-builder, constraints

I am setting the .Width and .Top NSLayoutConstraints on a UIImgeView instance inside my View Controller's `updateViewConstraints()`. In the XCode visual debugger i can see the constraints are actually set, but for some reason they are not being used (?) they appear un (content size) and are greyed out.
When i output the constraints using NSLog i can also see they are set, but somehow the image stays the original size ... 
 What does this mean?

```
constraints in parent: [<NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b379590 UIImageView:0x7af897b0.centerX == UIView:0x7b37d2e0.centerX>, 
                        <NSLayoutConstraint:0x7b36e3d0 V:|-(0)-[UIImageView:0x7af897b0]   (Names: '|':UIView:0x7b37d2e0 )>]
constraints in view: [<NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x7ae892b0 H:[UIImageView:0x7af897b0(301)] Hug:251 CompressionResistance:750>, 
                      <NSContentSizeLayoutConstraint:0x7ae834e0 V:[UIImageView:0x7af897b0(365)] Hug:251 CompressionResistance:750>]
```

[image]

Code that sets the constraints :

```
/// Image view with the character + ellipse
@IBOutlet weak var charImageView: UIImageView!

override func updateViewConstraints() {
      super.updateViewConstraints()
      charImageView.widthLayoutConstraint?.constant = 301.0
      charImageView.heightLayoutConstraint?.constant = 365.0
}
```

The extension i use to get `widthLayoutConstraint` and `heightLayoutConstraint`

```
extension UIView{
  /**
   Gets the width layout constraint defined as the NSLayoutConstraint whose first item is self and first attribute is Height
   */
  var heightLayoutConstraint:NSLayoutConstraint? {
      get{
          for constraint in constraints {
              if  constraint.firstItem as? UIView == self &&
                  constraint.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttribute.Height
              {
                  return constraint
              }
          }
          return nil
      }
  }

  /**
   Gets the width layout constraint defined as the NSLayoutConstraint whose first item is self and first attribute is Width
   */
  var widthLayoutConstraint:NSLayoutConstraint? {
      get{
          for constraint in constraints {
              if  constraint.firstItem as? UIView == self &&
                  constraint.firstAttribute == NSLayoutAttribute.Width
              {
                  return constraint
              }
          }
          return nil
      }
  }
}
```

This is how the layout constraints are added initially using IB. As you can see they are added for the Compact Width size Class, which i am using when i see the problem (iPhone4S simulator).

The constraints are already added via IB and i am updating their constant with code. The debugger shows clearly that the constant IS IN FACT UPDATED but somehow the image gets drawn in the original size.

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Grey color constraints show that these constraints are exist but not installed in your views.

Refer below image:

[image]

1. Select grey constraint
2. Open attribute inspector
3. At bottom you can see `Installed` option
4. If it is uncheck then enable this by clicking check mark
5. This will install selected constraint in your view

**Update:**

You can add `width` constraint using below code:

```
self.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(
        item: charImageView,
        attribute: .Width,
        relatedBy: .Equal,
        toItem: nil,
        attribute: .NotAnAttribute,
        multiplier: 1.0,
        constant: 301.0))
```

You can update constraint value using my other answer:

[Update constraint's constant value programatically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27414052/moving-views-with-constraints/27420696#27420696)

Comment: I am settings this constraints PROGRAMATICALLY inside updateViewConstraints()

Comment: @JuanCarlosOspinaGonzalez Can you please show your code?

Comment: please see. Thanks.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOspinaGonzalez: Please check updated answer

Comment: thanks but the constrainrs are added via IB and i would prefer to keep it that way.

The constraints are already added via IB and i am updating their constant with code. The debugger shows clearly that the constant IS IN FACT UPDATED but somehow the image gets drawn in the original size.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOspinaGonzalez: I think u forgot one important line here, `self.view.layoutIfNeeded()`. Add these line after setting constant value.

Comment: Thanks, tried that after setting the constant inside updateViewConstraints(). Didn't work.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOspinaGonzalez: Please check my other answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27414052/moving-views-with-constraints/27420696#27420696 & http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27438831/uitableview-height-does-not-change-dynamically-in-swift-ios/27440778#27440778

Comment: Setting to Less Than or Equal does the job! wow! much props to you! Can you update the original answer to point to that other one? i can then mark it as the right answer. Thanks!