# How to correct subviews location after resizing superview using iOS auto layout

Tags: ios, objective-c, constraints, autolayout

I have added a `UIImageView` to a `UIViewController`. I have used aspect ratio  layout constraint to it.
    [image]

I am adding some UITextFields programmatically into UIImageView.

```
  textField1.frame = CGRectMake(posx,posy,textWidth,textHeight);
  [self.imageView addSubview:textField1];
```

In some devices UIText fields are not properly positioned, because of the auto resizing.
I have tried to get the width of the resized UIImage.And proportionally position text fields but it is showing a single width and height value for every device. 
How can i fix this issue.

Comment: you should add constraints programmatically to textField1 according to your app logic.

Comment: Have a look on this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27414052/moving-views-with-constraints/27420696#27420696

Comment: @nyekimov thanks for the comment. My problem is how to get the resized factor of the super view.