# How would you center a UITextView as a subview of a UIView?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitextview

I have a UITextView that is inside a UIView. I managed to center a UITextView using the following code:

```
self.textView.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentCenter;
```

Right now, the text is center within the UITextView, but I would also like to center the UITextView within a UIView.

How can I achieve this?

I have tried the following code, but it seems to do nothing.

```
[self.textView setCenter:CGPointMake(self.topView.frame.size.width/2 - self.textView.frame.size.width/2, self.topView.frame.size.height/2)];
```

Thanks

Comment: Try `self.textView.center = urView.center ` or set horizontal and vertical alignment constraints.

Comment: How is the text view created? Storyboard? Xib? Code? Are you using constraints or auto layout?

Comment: @rmaddy, the text view is created in Storyboard using constaints

Comment: Then most likely the constraints prevent you from setting the center. Setup the constraints properly to center the text view.

Comment: I set the Text View with Horizontal and Vertical Center constraints within the UIView, but no changes were made

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to do here some math calculations.

> Center = (superView.size / 2) - (subView.size / 2);

So you have to divide superview.size (width & height) by 2, make it half size. And then divide subview.size by half to adjust center point in frame.

See below code will works for you.

```
CGFloat centerX = (self.topView.frame.size.width / 2) - (self.textView.frame.size.width / 2);
CGFloat centerY = (self.topView.frame.size.height / 2) - (self.textView.frame.size.height / 2);

CGRect rect = self.textView.frame;
rect.origin.x = centerX;
rect.origin.y = centerY;
[self.textView setFrame:rect];
```

Make sure that `AutoLyout` is disable for application. I mean

[image]

But If you have supported Auto layout than this will not work. For that you have to set constraint on textView for position x and position y.

have a look on **[Moving views with constraints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27414052/moving-views-with-constraints/27420696#27420696)**  to set auto layout constraints.

Comment: hi kampai, I do have auto layout enabled. Looking at your other thread, when you say constraint for position x and position y, do you mean I need to setup constraints for the Top and Bottom of the text view to be x pixels away from topView?

Comment: thanks, there's no way to do this programmatically with Auto Layout enabled?

Comment: Actually auto layout restrict views to change their size and position, how ever I will search for other way and I'll keep u update tomorrow.

Comment: thanks Kampai!..One last question, in regards to your other thread, does this also mean that since I have Auto Layout enabled, if I wanted to use animations to achieve what the other poster did, it will not work?

Comment: Animations will work. Just we need to take when we position or change size which is different than Storyboard. But If u created view by code than you dont need to use constraints for that.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
[self.textView setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
[self.textView setCenter:self.topView.center];
```