# How to update constraint of a UILabel programatically

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel, nslayoutconstraint

I am creating a `UILabel` in stroyboard which frame is `(15, 55, 250, 20)`.
According to my requirement I want to change that label frame to `(15, 10, 250, 20)` through coding. But there is no affect on that label.

So I update constraint through coding like below:

```
mylabel.frame = CGRectMake(15, 10, 250, 20);
[mylabel needsUpdateConstraints];
```

But it's not working. Please anybody help me. I am stuck on this from last 2 days.

I am adding these constraint through storyboard

[image]

Comment: Your are setting the frame, not updating constraints.  Did you add any constraints in the storyboard?

Comment: Yeah, I am adding constraints in the storyboard

Comment: What constraints did you add?

Comment: I update my question please check . I add a screenshot for constarint

Comment: You say you want to change it's origin to {15,10}, but the constraints you show already have the view there. Do you mean you want to change it to {15,55}?

Comment: Yes i need to change the y-position, If its {15, 10}, then it will be {15,55}.

Comment: Objective-C or Swift? Specify it in your tags.

Comment: I have explained everything here. Have  a look on this answer - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27414052/moving-views-with-constraints/27420696#27420696

Answer (score 0):

Updating frames does not work well with AutoLayout. Create and animate constraints instead.

Here's how you can create a `NSLayoutConstraint` and add it to the view:

```
var myLabelConstraint = NSLayoutConstraint (item: myLabel,
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top, // You can also choose Width, Height, Bottom, Leading, Trailing
        relatedBy: NSLayoutRelation.Equal,
        toItem: self.view
        attribute: NSLayoutAttribute.Top,
        multiplier: 1,
        constant: 10)
    self.view.addConstraint(myLabelConstraint)
```

If you are creating a constraint for width and height, remember to change `toItem` into `nil` and `attribute` into `NSLayoutAttribute.NotAnAttribute`.

If you want to animate a constraint just change the `constant` of it:

```
myConstraint.constant = 15
self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you should delete the one constraint to the right edge of the screen (45); you're over constraining your view.

When you want to change a constraint you made in the storyboard, you should make an IBOutlet to it, and modify its constant value in code. Since you want to change the y position, make an outlet to the vertical spacing constraint (the 10 one), I'll call it yCon for this example. You only need to do this,

```
self.yCon.constant = 55;
[self.view layoutIfNeeded];
```

Comment: I make an IBOutlet for constraint @property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *yCon; . But how to add and with whom i have to add in story board please guide me

Comment: @SRNayak, you add it to the vertical constraint that you made. It's easiest to do that from the scene list on the left rather than from the canvas.