# UIView Animation not working in iOS 7

Tags: ios, animation, ios7, core-animation

The following code working in iOS 8 and not in iOS 7.

```
 [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5
                          delay:0.0
                        options: UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseIn
                     animations:^{
                         self.toolsview.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height-68, self.view.frame.size.width, 68);
                     }
                     completion:^(BOOL finished){   }];
```

Even this method is compatible from iOS 4, this is not working in iOS 7. 
Initially i have set view frame to

```
self.toolsview.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.view.frame.size.height, self.view.frame.size.width, 68);
```

Comment: Not working? Elaborate more, what you expect? what you got?

Comment: changing the frame size with animation, it will move upwards from bottom of the screen

Comment: Have you set auto layout for this view?

Comment: yes, auto layout used

Comment: The reason here is auto layout will not allow to update view frames programatically due to minimise the conflicts with other views. You need to use `constant` property of auto layout constraints.

Comment: This is a similar post to answer your question - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27414052/moving-views-with-constraints/27420696#27420696

Comment: facing this problem only in iOS 7. thanks ll check for constant property..

Comment: Put a static CGRect instead and see if it works, And do check if self.toolsView Outlet is connected, if so, disconnect and connect it once again

Comment: Which constraints have you given to "toolsview"?

Answer (score 1):

As Kampai says in his comments, you can't reliably manipulate a view's frame with AutoLayout in force. AutoLayout tends to force you view's settings back to those defined by it's constraints.

Instead, set height, width, left edge and top edge constraints (or whatever you need) connect them as outlets, and manipulate their constant values, then call layoutIfNeeded from inside your animation block.